# CONVERT A NUMBER LIKE 45615564.5441 TO 45,615,564 IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a decimal number to money type and don't want to write numbers after comma EX: 1777888.47 --> 1,777,888
Could you help me ? Thanks alot.

Comment: This is called *rounding*. Have you tried the `ROUND()`, `FLOOR()` or `CEILING()` functions?

Comment: Why? This sort of transform should not be done at the data layer.

Comment: i suggest you to just give currency instead of converting the data

Comment: select format(round(1777888.47,0),'N0')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"N0" you can't.  Ha, ha.  That's actually a pun.  You can do this with the `'N0'` formatting option (and converting to a number with no decimal points):

```
format(cast(1777888.47 as decimal(18, 0)), 'N0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute this query.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(100), cast(71567536.100000 as money), 1)+ N' ر.س ' as 'Budget'
```